# spring boot redis starter get ERR string exceeds maximum allowed size (512MB)

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-boot

I was trying to integrate redis with spring boot and I was using spring boot redis stater dependency. I follow the spring boot official guide with the configuration:

```
#redis
spring.redis.database= 1
spring.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.redis.password=
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.pool.max-active=8
spring.redis.pool.max-wait=-1
```

The redis associated code is as follows:

```
@Autowired
StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

ValueOperations<String, String> ops = stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue();
ops.set(phoneNumber, vc, DateTime.now().plusMinutes(5).getMillis());
```

The `phonenumber` is a 11 length string, `vc` is a 6 length string.

But when I run the application, I got the error as the title shows

```
ERR string exceeds maximum allowed size (512MB); nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR string exceeds maximum allowed size (512MB)
```

Am I missing something???

Answer (score 1):

So after a while of digging the source code of spring boot data redis, it turns out that the api I was using, which omits a `TimeUnit param`, is used for saving data with offset. To set the timeout param, I have to give a TimeUnit param which is represented by another set api with 4 params as `(key, value, long, TimeUnit)`... Sometime without java doc, it's kinda struggling.